# Prove $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{y^2}$ is not a convex function on the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x>0, y>0 \}$ without using Hessian

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

### Summary

**Known**: $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{y^2}$ is not a convex function on the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x>0, y>0 \}$. This can be proved by the Hessian of the function.

**Questions**: How can we prove the local non-convexity without using the second-order condition?

### $f(x,y)$ being a non-convex function on the set  $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x>0, y>0 \}$

By the Hessian of the function:
$$ \nabla^2 f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\frac{2}{y^3} \\ -\frac{2}{y^3} & \frac{6x}{y^4}
\end{bmatrix}$$

On the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x>0, y>0 \}$, $\nabla^2f(x,y)$ is a sign-indefinite matrix. By the second-order conditions, we conclude that the function $f(x,y)$ is locally non-convex on the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x>0, y>0 \}$.

### Attempt:

I try to show the non-convexity by the basic definition,i.e., $\exists (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, x>0, y>0, \theta\in[0,1] $ such that $$ f(\theta x_1 + (1-\theta)x_2) \geq \theta f(x_1) + (1-\theta) f(x_2)$$

Hence, try to verify the following is negative for some $x_1,x_2,\theta$:
$$ \theta f(x_1,y_1) + (1-\theta) f(x_2,y_2) - f(\theta x_1 + (1-\theta) x_2, \theta y_1 + (1-\theta) y_2) = \theta \frac{x_1}{y_1^2} + (1-\theta)\frac{x_2}{y_2^2} - \frac{\theta x_1 + (1-\theta)x_2}{(\theta y_1 + (1-\theta)y_2)^2}$$
However, I lost the direction and don't know how to proceed from here. I presume I'll need some inequality to do so but couldn't think of a proper one.

### Questions

How to prove the local non-convexity of $f(x,y)$ by the convexity definition or other approach than the second-order condition?

---

### Motivation of the problem

I'm trying to prove the convexity of a parametric constrained optimization problem, which is a semidefinite program for a given parameter. I manage to reformulate my constrained into linear matrix inequalities, which are convex. However my objective function become nonlinear as the following:
$$ \frac{\lambda_{max}(P)}{y^2},$$
where $P$ and $y$ are decision variables and $\lambda_{max}(\cdot)$ is the largest eigenvalue of the matrix $P$. The constraints include $P$ being a positive definite matrix and $y$ being positive. If this function is a locally convex function, we can conclude the optimal value function in the parametric optimization problem is convex in its parameter by the paper from [Fiacco and Kyparisis](https://rdcu.be/cSFbV).

Before tackling the exact problem, I attempt to solve the similar but less complex problem I asked above to find possible approaches for my exact problem.

Comment: $\nabla^2f(x,y)$ is *not* a positive semi-definite matrix. Its determinant is $-4/y^6 < 0$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for pointing this out. I was wrong on the definiteness of the Hessian.

Comment: I've updated the post according to the fact that this function is non-convex on the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x>0, y>0 \}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U\subset \Bbb R^d$ be open and let $f\colon  U\to\Bbb R$.

Let's analyse the notion of the convexity. Observe that the condition $$f(\theta x_1 + (1-\theta)x_2) \leq \theta f(x_1) + (1-\theta) f(x_2)$$ is one-dimensional in it's nature. We consider any segment $I=[x_1,x_2]\subset U$ and $f|I$ has to be convex.

In other words, for any $a\in \Bbb R^d$ (we can take $a$ only from $U$) and $ v\in \Bbb R^d$ we define the function $f_{a,v}(t)=f(a+tv)$ for such $t\in\Bbb R$ that $a+tv\in U$. Now we can say that $f$ is convex iff $f_{a,v}$ is convex for any $a\in U$ and $ v\in \Bbb R^d$.

Now we are ready to analyse the situation from the question.

In order to show that some function $f$ isn't convex it sufficies to find some line or segment lying on the domain such that the function $f$ restricted to that line or segment isn't convex. Having a point $p=(a,b)\in U:=\{x,y>0\}$ and $v=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ we can consider
$$f_{p,v}(t)=f(a+tv_1,b+tv_2)=\frac{a+t\cos\alpha}{(b+t\sin\alpha)^2}.$$

Now it's easier to analyse $f$ by analysing $f_{p,v}$ near $0$. We can draw it's graph, we can calculate the derivative. I checked the graph of $f_{p,v}$ for $p=(1,1)$ and I saw that for small positive $\alpha$ the function $f_{p,v}$ is concave near $0$. I didn't try to prove it analytically.

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer, @Mateo. I wonder how you chose $p$ and $v$ in this case?

Comment: I used Desmos, where I could take $a,b,\alpha$ as parameters. It seems the point $p$ is arbitrary, since the function is nowhere locally convex. I for example used $p=(1,1)$. Then I changed $\alpha$ and observed that for $\alpha\approx 0$ and $\alpha\approx\pi$ there is concavity near $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination. Now I see you choose $v$ this way to parameterize direction with $\alpha$. This approach and using visual tool are very helpful. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

A quick verification can demonstrate that your function is not convex. Consider the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix:

$$ \left\{\frac{3 x-\sqrt{9 x^2+4 y^2}}{y^4},\frac{\sqrt{9 x^2+4 y^2}+3 x}{y^4}\right\}. $$

The one on the left can clearly be negative. Thus, the matrix is not PSD.

Alternatively, you can build a plot of the function for $x>0,y>0$ and verify it visually.

Comment: Thank you, @Oleh. Also, thank you for the suggesting on checking it visually. To this end, would you be able to visualize convexity if the function domain is in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 2):

Here is $x/y^2$ on the line $x=t,y=1+t$
[image]
Of course it is not convex.

For an explicit example, take $t=1/2$ and $t=3/2$.  Then the example is:
$$
(1,2) = \frac12\left[\left(\frac12,\frac32\right) + \left(\frac32,\frac52\right)\right]
$$
but
$$
f(1,2) \le \frac12\left[f\left(\frac12,\frac32\right) + f\left(\frac32,\frac52\right)\right]
$$
is false, since
$$
\frac14 \le \frac12\left[\frac29+\frac{6}{25}\right]
$$
is false.

Comment: Thank you, @GEdgar. I wonder how you pick the direction $(1,1)$ and offset $(0,1)$ of this line based on my problem? Is there an approach that might apply to other problems?

Comment: First I tried a line through the origin, it didn't work. So then I tried another line; this one was the simplest to think of.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Sharing the process you get to the answer is very helpful for me!